# Are the two types of lustra distinguishable?

Tags: word-comparison, resource-request, vowel-quantity

One meaning of the word *lustrum* is a sacrifice for purification done every five years; another is a house of ill repute. I'd always figured that the two were complete homophones.

However, someone told me recently that the sacrifice has a long *ū* in its stem, while the debauchery has a short *ŭ*, which would be a convenient way to tell them apart.

Is this true? How can I check? My usual reference source is L&S, which unfortunately doesn't mark vowel quantity in closed syllables (…or even consistently in open ones); Wiktionary does show different vowel lengths, but I'm not sure where it gets that information from or how reliable it is.

Answer (score 4):

My Latin-Dutch dictionary (Muller-Renkema, 1970) lists the debauchery, without the macron, as first lemma, saying it’s related to **lŭtum**, mud.

The sacrifice, with the macron, is related to **lūstro**, which in itself has two meanings.

1. illuminate, derived from a reconstructed form *leuk-s-trom*
2. purify, derived from a reconstructed form lŏu(e)s-trom cf. ἐ-λοϜεσ-σα vid. lăvo

I have no way of validating these reconstructed forms, but maybe this is something to go by.